# sed command to search for multiple strings in a file

Tags: shell, sed

I need to search multiple strings in a html file and then exclude the searched portion of that string and save rest of the portion to a file.

My file is like

```
<td colspan="2" class="suite-unknown">
<td colspan="2" class="suite-fail">
<span style="margin: 2px; padding: 1px">&nbsp;</span>TCS-209
<span style="margin: 2px; padding: 1px">&nbsp;</span>[TC-001] User validates login
<td colspan="2" class="suite-unknown">
<td colspan="2" class="suite-pass">
<span style="margin: 2px; padding: 1px">&nbsp;</span>TCS-210
<span style="margin: 2px; padding: 1px">&nbsp;</span>[TC-002] user close browser
```

I tried many options :
Failed options :

```
sed -n ('/<span style="margin: 2px; padding: 1px/p'|'/td colspan="2" class="suite-/p') report.html
```

Another one :

```
sed -n '/\/<span style="margin: 2px; padding: 1px\|*td colspan="2" class="suite/p' report.html
```

My keywords for search are : `<span style="margin: 2px; padding: 1px` and `td colspan="2" class="suite`.

And then once its searched i need to exclude the search keywords of the string and print the rest.

Means output be like :

```
-unknown
-fail
TCS-209
[TC-001] User validates login
unknown
pass
TCS-210
[TC-002] user close browser
```

Please help

Comment: It's usually better to use HTML-aware tools to parse HTML.

Comment: which one is that ? @choroba

Comment: I often use [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) which is based on libxml, it can handle html if it's not too terrible. There are probably many more.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n 's/^ *<td colspan="2" class="suite\(.*\)">/\1/p;s/^ *<span style="margin: 2px; padding: 1px.*<\/span>//p' myfile
```

This is not the best way to extract information from HTML, but it will do for something as simple as this.

```
curl -s 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aruiz-caritsqa/wdio-html-format-reporter/master/wdio-report.html' | sed  -n 's/^ *<td colspan="2" class="suite\(.*\)">/\1/p;s/^ *<span style="margin: 2px; padding: 1px.*<\/span>//p'
```

gives me

```
-unknown
some example tests for a readme.md demo
-pass
should be a passing test
-fail
should have a failing test
-pass
Full page screenshot
```

Comment: It didnt work for me. It printed everything in that page

Comment: Then perhaps your file is not like what you've put in your question.  I copied it, pasted it into a file, ran the command above and obtained the result you desired.  Perhaps you can upload your real file somewhere and share it with us?

Comment: https://github.com/aruiz-caritsqa/wdio-html-format-reporter/blob/master/wdio-report.html

Comment: you can find the file here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In your example, you didn't have leading spaces as in the file.  I'll correct my command.

Comment: Sorry, corrected again and showing usage and results.